# Fixing lstlisting inside exsheets question and solution environments

Tags: listings, exsheets

I am trying to use `exsheets` to prepare the tests for Foundation of Programming exam.
I need to include snippets of C code in some `question` and `solution` and I am going to use `listings` (with the options specified in the *minimal working example* below).
However I realised that the code is messed up if injected inside a `question` or a `solution`.

Do you know how to work around the problem?

---

**Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\lstset{
  frame=single,
  xleftmargin=20pt,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\small,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{6}
Consider the following C program.
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
Consider the following C program.
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{solution}

\pagebreak
\printsolutions 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `exsheets` uses `environ`'s `\NewEnviron` internall which effectively means that the body of the `question` and `solution` are treated like arguments of a macro. As a consequence verbatim material is not allowed inside. @Gonzalo's solution thus is the way to go.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

You can box your listing first, and then use the box in questions and/or solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\lstset{
frame=single,
xleftmargin=20pt,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
tabsize=2,
breaklines,
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
language=C,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray}}


\newsavebox\myboxa

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\myboxa}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{question}{6}
Consider the following C program.\par
\noindent\usebox\myboxa
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
Consider the following C program.\par
\noindent\usebox\myboxa
\end{solution}
\printsolutions 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo, thanks for your kind reply! I am not confident with minipages and boxes, however I would say that the solution is a bit cumbersome... I would like to put a question and a solution in a separate file to include, while I would have to add definitions to the preamble as well... am I right?

Comment: You are right, I forgot to include `relsize` package. I changed `\smaller` to `\small` as you did to fix the problem.

Comment: This helped a lot, I just spent an afternoon trying to panelbeat code into the pseudo environment, when Clemens pointed me to this post.

Answer (score 5):

I was directed to this post because I also had a `verbatim` problem with `exsheets`.
Some more google directed me to the package [cprotect](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cprotect) which is supposed to solved exactly the problem we are facing (using verbatim environments where they should not be usable :-))

I got working the original example with the addition of a `\usepackage{cprotect}`
and putting a `\cprotEnv` in front of the question and solution environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\lstset{
  frame=single,
  xleftmargin=20pt,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\small,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray}
}

\begin{document}

\cprotEnv \begin{question}{6}
Consider the following C program.
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{question}

\cprotEnv \begin{solution}
Consider the following C program.
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{solution}

\pagebreak
\printsolutions 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This breaks optional arguments to `\begin{solution}`!

Answer (score 2):

Since version 0.10 (2013/10/24) `exsheets` comes with an additional package called `exsheets-listings` which provides the environments `lstquestion` and `lstsolution` that can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{exsheets-listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  frame=single,
  xleftmargin=20pt,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\small,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray}
}
\SetupExSheets{
  question/listings={style=mystyle} ,
  solution/listings={style=mystyle}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstquestion}[pre=Consider the following C program.,points=6]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
\end{lstquestion}

\begin{lstsolution}[pre=Consider the following C program.]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
\end{lstsolution}

% \pagebreak
\printsolutions 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution allows the inclusion of exactly one listing in a question, and it is awkward to use, as the text preceding or following the listing has to be passed using an option. What about if more than a listing is needed in a question? And what about other `verbatim`-like environments (`minted`, for instance)? Maybe it is reasonable to not use `environ` in the package at all. Can you comment on that?

Comment: @Romildo If I don't use `environ` I can't allow the selective inclusion of questions and solutions which is one of the main features and to me personally is more important than code listings.

Comment: @Romildo The solution of Gonzalo would of course work with more than one listing