# Converting latex to html using exsheets, and keeping equations as latex

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax, exsheets

I have been successfully using the configuration described in the excellent answer to [keeping equations as latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185791/converting-latex-to-html-but-keeping-equations-as-latex), so as to use MathJax.  Now I wish to also use the exsheets package (for creating questions with solutions), which is compatible with tex4ht *except* that displayed equations don't work inside a question environment (provided one wishes to keep equations as latex, as I do).

Specifically, the tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

This first question compiles fine:
\begin{question}
Here's an inline equation: \( a=0 \).  
\end{question}

This next question produces desired output, but gives error ``Missing \} inserted'':
\begin{question}
Here's a displayed equation (using brackets)
\[ x=1 \]
\end{question}

This last question gives errors ''Argument of verbatim has an extra \}'' and ''Paragraph ended before verbatim was complete'':
\begin{question}
Here's a displayed equation (using equation*)
\begin{equation}
  y=2
\end{equation}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

with configuration file

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\Preamble{html}

\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
%\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link href="basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\Hnewline}} 
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                           
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {           
      extensions: ["color.js"], 
      equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" }         
    },        
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], 
    tex2jax: {       
      \unexpanded{
      inlineMath: [ ['\$','\$'], ["\\\(","\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
      processEscapes: true,
      processEnvironments: true
    }                   
  });                  
  </script>\Hnewline
}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{ <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> \Hnewline}}

\newtoks\eqtoks
\def\AltMathOne#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
\HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMathOne} 
\def\AltlMath#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
\HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{()}{\AltlMath}{}
\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\eqtoks{\[#1\]}%
\HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
  \renewenvironment{#1}{%
    \NoFonts%
    \string\begin\{#1\}%
  \verbatim}{\endverbatim\string\end\{#1\}\EndNoFonts}%
}

\VerbMath{align}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{equation*}

\EndPreamble
```

produces the output

[image]

Inside of the question environment, inline equations compile just fine, while displayed equations with brackets output ok but compile with an error, and displayed equations using `equation` do not produce the desired output.

---

**Update:** I realize now this issue is caused by the fact that verbatim material is not allowed inside exsheets environments; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131546/fixing-lstlisting-inside-exsheets-question-and-solution-environments).  So I'm wondering if a command similar to VerbMath can be defined without using the verbatim package, i.e. a command that will keep the entirety of \begin{equation} EQUATION HERE \end{equation} unchanged in the html output, so as to be processed by MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've slightly corrected the configurations, `\detokenize` instead of token register is used now. I've moved all configurations from the `.cfg` file to standalone package, which is now part of [helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) bundle. It is named `mathjax-latex-4ht.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \Configure{VERSION}{}
  \Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
  \Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
  %\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link href="basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\Hnewline}} 
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
      <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                           
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        TeX: {           
          extensions: ["color.js"], 
          equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" }         
        },        
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], 
        tex2jax: {       
          \unexpanded{
            inlineMath: [ ['\$','\$'], ["\\\(","\\\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
          processEscapes: true,
          processEnvironments: true
        }                   
      });                  
      </script>\Hnewline
    }}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{ <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> \Hnewline}}
  \newtoks\eqtoks
  \def\AltMathOne#1${\HCode{\detokenize{$#1$}}$}
  \Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMathOne} 
  \def\AltlMath#1\){\HCode{\detokenize{\(#1\)}}\)}
  \Configure{()}{\AltlMath}{}
  \def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\HCode{\detokenize{\[#1\]}}\]}
  \Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
}
% 
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
  \renewenvironment{#1}{%
    \NoFonts%
    \string\begin\{#1\}%
      \verbatim}{\endverbatim\string\end\{#1\}\EndNoFonts}%
}

\VerbMath{align}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{equation*}
```

What changed are declarations of math scrapping commands:

```
  \def\AltMathOne#1${\HCode{\detokenize{$#1$}}$}
  \def\AltlMath#1\){\HCode{\detokenize{\(#1\)}}\)}
  \def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\HCode{\detokenize{\[#1\]}}\]}
```

You can simplify the `.cfg` file now:

```
\RequirePackage{mathjax-latex-4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

You still need it in order to load the `mathjax-latex-4ht` package, but you don't need any custom configurations.

The issue with verbatim is more serious, easiest solution which I can think of unfortunately means to modify the document and use command which will output an environment when compiled with `latex` and verbatim code with `tex4ht`.

We need to provide a package for this command, `verbtexmath.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{verbtexmath}
\newcommand\myverbenv[2]{%
  \begin{#1}%
    #2%
  \end{#1}%
}

\endinput
```

and `tex4ht` configuration, `verbtexmath.4ht`:

```
\renewcommand\myverbenv[2]{%
  \string\begin\{#1\}%
  \HCode{\Hnewline\detokenize{#2}\Hnewline}
  \string\end\{#1\}
}
```

As I said, you have to modify the document slightly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbtexmath}

\begin{document}

This first question compiles fine:


\begin{question}
Here's an inline equation:\( a=0 \) 

and $b = 1$
\end{question}


Outside question \(a = 0\) and $b=1$ 

\[a=3\]

This next question produces desired output, but gives error ``Missing \} inserted'':

\begin{question}
Here's a displayed equation (using brackets)

\[c=4\]
\end{question}

This last question gives errors ''Argument of verbatim has an extra \}'' and ''Paragraph ended before verbatim was complete'':

\begin{question}
Here's a displayed equation (using equation*)

\myverbenv{equation}{y=2}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Important line is:

```
 \myverbenv{equation}{y=2}
```

this will create `equation` environment with `y=2` content.

The resulting document:

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thank you very much.  I may not get to test it in my context until next week.  It seems like this solution would be easily adaptable to other equation environments, such as align, am I correct?

Comment: @user59959 yes, you can use any environment name you need as a first parameter

Comment: This works perfectly, and I'm perfectly content with modifying the document with the new command.