# No images in htlatex (tex4ht)

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

How do I configure htlatex so that equations are not rendered as an image in a separate file, but within the document as in `$x$`?  I still would like the ability to assign `\label`

Answer (score 5):

I think that it is best to convert math to MathML and use MathJax to render it. Native LaTeX labels work with no problems this way.

All we need to do is to use simple config file, which will provide some JavaScript to load MathJax:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\Configure{@HEAD}{%
\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML">
 </script>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

All what this does is that it selects MathML output in the `\Preamble` command and then include external script to load MathJax. Important piece is `MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML`, which configures MathJax to parse only MathML and to select common html as the rendered format. MathJax by default also parse LaTeX math in the document, but we really don't need that, it would only slow down the processing.

Some sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

hello world

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:hello}
a = \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}
\end{equation} 

See equation~\ref{eq:hello}

Now some multiline

\begin{multline*}
  p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\ 
  - 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multline*}


Align:

\begin{align*} 
  2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
  3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}


Align*:

\begin{align*}
  x&=y           &  w &=z              &  a&=b+c\\
  2x&=-y         &  3w&=\frac{1}{2}z   &  a&=b\\
  -4 + 5x&=2+y   &  w+2&=-1+w          &  ab&=cb
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

We can compile it using

```
make4ht -uc configfilename.cfg filename.tex
```

and the result looks this way:

[image]

Comment: I upvoted and I'll play around with this, thanks, but right now I was just looking to reproduce the same behavior as $...$ (which does not use mathjax).  I don't want to use javascript here.

Comment: @EmanueleViola it works with `$...$` as well. If you don't want to use JavaScript, then it is possible to install command line version of MathJax using `node.js` and convert the HTML file with MathML to simplified version. I can update the answer with an example.

Comment: I am trying to produce a very minimalistic html here that can be pasted into wordpress.  Wordpress doesn't like javascript (as far as I can tell).  The way $...$ is converted is just plain HTML, which Wordpress understands, but for some reason \begin{equation} is rendered as an image, which wordpress does not like.

Comment: @EmanueleViola ah I see. [This might be useful](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265916/2891) then.