# exsheets mdframed solutions with figure

Tags: subfloats, mdframed, exsheets

I'm having an issue with adding a frame around the solutions environment while using the exsheets package.  I have a bit of my code below.  My problem is that I'm greeted with an error if I choose to add a `\begin{figure}` environment within the boxed solution.  I've tried a number of workarounds, including modifying my `\begin{figure}\end{figure}` to, instead, be a `\begin{center}\end{center}`.  However, I also have instances where I wish to use `\begin{subfigure}\end{subfigure}`.  As such, I've tried modifying these subfigures to, instead, use `\begin{minipage}\end{minipage}`; however, this overly complicates the layout and then the captions are not labelled as I would desire.  I've also tried the suggestion given for list environments found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49129/lrbox-in-newenvironment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131546/fixing-lstlisting-inside-exsheets-question-and-solution-environments).  The error I receive while using the figure environment within the mdframe is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

...

! Undefined control sequence.
\@xfloat ...@fltovf \fi \global \setbox \@currbox 
                                                  \color@vbox \normalcolor \...
```

I would like to include figures (and ultimately subfigures) in the mdframed solutions.  Thanks in advance, and any/all help is much appreciated.

MWE

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % Frames For exsheets
\usepackage{exsheets}                   % Creating Exercises and Solutions

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Sub-Section}

\begin{question}
    Here's a question
\end{question}
\mdframed
\begin{solution}[print=true]
    Here's a solutions.
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}
        \caption{diagram}
        \label{fig:solution}
    \end{figure}
\end{solution}
\endmdframed

\end{document}
```

Per the comment from @leandriis, I've managed to get something working.  This is not ideal, as I cannot seem to caption my "sub-images" appropriately; however, here is a close work around.  Still hopeful for a solid solution that would keep subfloats and subcaptions intact.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % Frames For exsheets
\usepackage{exsheets}                   % Creating Exercises and Solutions
\usepackage{capt-of}                    % Add Captions to Images

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Sub-Section}

\begin{question}
    Here's a question
\end{question}
\mdframed
\begin{solution}[print=true]
    Here's a solutions.

    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}
            \label{fig:solution-left}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}
            \label{fig:solution-right}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \captionof{figure}{one caption for all images, just not subs}
\end{solution}
\endmdframed

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you can remove the figure environment and replace caption with captionof from the caption package.

Comment: Actually, using the \capt-of package might be the answer.  I've just had success with the mdframed solutions, center environment, and captionof.  I'll see if I can get the subfloats---i.e., minipage---working.  I might just have to write a new command or environment to make a short cut for my subfigures.  Thanks for the tip @leandriis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE contains two different possibilities on how you can get subfigures with referenceable captions inside of your framed solution block. In the first one, I have used the `float` package in combination with the `H` option for the `figure` environment Subfigures are inside of the `subfigure` environment by the `subcaption` package. In the second example I have used `minipages` as well as `\captionsetup{figure}` and `\subcaptionbox`(also from the `subcaption`)  package. The output of both approaches is similar:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % Frames For exsheets
\usepackage{exsheets}                   % Creating Exercises and Solutions
\usepackage{subcaption}                 % For subfigures with captions (subcaptionbox or subfigure)
\usepackage{float}                      % For the H option (disables floating of figure environment)
%\usepackage{changepage}                 % For the adjustbox environment

%\usepackage{showframe}                  % Shows the border of the textblock. Don't use in real document
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Sub-Section}


\begin{question}
    Here's a question
\end{question}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-10pt}{-10pt}
\mdframed
\begin{solution}[print=true]
    Here's a solutions.

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{my left subfigure}
            \label{fig:solution-left}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{my right subfigure}
            \label{fig:solution-right}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{one caption for all images, just not subs}
    \end{figure}

\end{solution}
\endmdframed
%\end{adjustwidth}

\ref{fig:solution-left}

\ref{fig:solution-right}


\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Sub-Section}


\begin{question}
    Here's a question
\end{question}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-10pt}{-10pt}
\mdframed
\begin{solution}[print=true]
    Here's a solutions.

\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \captionsetup{type=figure}
      \subcaptionbox{my left subfigure\label{fig:solution-left2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}} \hfill
      \subcaptionbox{my right subfigure\label{fig:solution-right2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \caption{one caption for all images, just not subs}
    \end{minipage}

\end{solution}
\endmdframed
%\end{adjustwidth}

\ref{fig:solution-left2}

\ref{fig:solution-right2}



\end{document}
```

---

Side note regarding parts of the code that are currently commented out: As you can see from the above MWE (better visible if you comment in `showframe`), the left margin of the mdframed box is aligned with the left margin:

[image]

Since there is a small horizontal white space between the frame and the beginning of the text inside of the box (`innerleftmargin`, default = 10 pt according to the manual) the word "Soution" is not aligned with the word "Exercise" any more. If you prefer thouse worde to be aligned and want the frame to occupy a little bit of space in the left (and right)  margin, you can comment in the `changepage` package and the corresponding `adjustwidth` environment. This will allow the mdframed box to use an additional 10 pt of the left and the right margin respectively leading to the following alignment:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the above clarification and accepted solution, @leandriis.  This is exactly what I am looking for.  Also, I love the added touch of the margin issues with solution boxes.  I actually prefer the original method of keeping the box inline with the section numbers; however, I can easily see that others might prefer the adjustment.